# Why can Poisson White Noise look similar in shape to Gaussian WN?

Tags: self-study

[image]

[image]

The equations for Gaussian prob dense func and Poisson prob mass func are very different, so why can these shapes look so similar?

Thank you!

Comment: One consequence of the central limit theorem is that a poisson variable with a largeish rate parameter is approximately normally distributed. It looks like your poisson parameter is about 10, if you plot the pmf of such a poisson variable, it will looks quite similar to a normal with mean and variance 10.

Comment: Thank you Matthew! The CLT states that with big enough sample size, sample mean approximates the population mean. I'm trying to see how that concept ties into your statement that a poisson variable that has a largeish rate parameter, its pmf will look quite similar to a normal.